# Breaking words into the letter pattern: code not working as expected

Tags: r

I have a list words and a list of common character patterns found within words. The script works by running through the word list and then checks what character pattern are found within the word and finally display the results in table.

The finished table should look like:

```
word    CharPatLen  charpat01 charpat02 charpat03 charpat04
father  4           f         a         th        er
there   3           th        er        e
after   4           a         f         r         er
```

Instead,  I get the table below and things start to go wrong on the field charpat03 for the word "there". The 'f' here should be instead of an 'e' and the following row is blank.

```
word    CharPatLen  charpat01 charpat02 charpat03 charpat04
father  4           f         a         th        er
there   3           th        er        f
after   4
```

I am also get the following warning message which which I tried to fix through google searches with no luck

```
'Warning message:
In as.numeric(paste(as.numeric(charIndexStart), charIndexEnd, sep = "")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion'
```

Help! I am not sure whats going wrong with the script.

Thanks, for taking the time to view my post.

```
##################################################
# This script loops through a word list then break the word into character (char)
# pattern found character pattern list 
# 
# e.g 
#using the word list         ( father, there, after)
#using the char pattern list (th,er,f, a, e,t)
# 
# it should return the following
# 
# word    CharPatLen  charpat01 charpat02 charpat03 charpat04
# father  4           f         a         th        er
# there   3           th        er        e
# after   4           a         f         r         er
#####################################################


word      <- c("father", "there", "after")
CharPatLen <- c(0, 0, 0)
charpat01 <- c("", "", "" )
charpat02 <- c("", "", "" )
charpat03 <- c("", "", "" )
charpat04 <- c("", "", "" )
charpat05 <- c("", "", "" )
wordList <- data.frame(word, CharPatLen, charpat01,charpat02,charpat03,charpat04,charpat05,stringsAsFactors = F)

textPat <- c("th", "er", "f","a","e","t")
frequency <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
textPattern <- data.frame(textPat,frequency, stringsAsFactors = F)


#######################################
# 01 loop through word list              
#######################################
for (text in wordList$word) {#4loop01
  # track what parts of the word a found char pattern
  charSelectionTracker <- rep(1, times=nchar(text))

  #found char patterns from word, order/range and the char pattern
  FoundcharPatternholder  <- data.frame(order= integer(),charPattern = character())

  #########################################
  # 02 loop through character patterns list  
  #########################################
     for (pattern in textPattern$textPat) { #4loop02


       if(sum(charSelectionTracker)== 0)
       {#charSelect

         #reorder patterns
         rank <- order(FoundcharPatternholder$order)
         FoundcharPatternholder<- FoundcharPatternholder[rank,]

         wordList[which(wordList$word == text),"CharPatLen"] = nrow(FoundcharPatternholder)

         for (patPao in 1:nrow(FoundcharPatternholder))
          {
           wordList[which(wordList$word == text),patPao+2] = as.character(FoundcharPatternholder[patPao,2])
           }

         break
       }#charSelect 

        #find all char pattern in word
        patFoundAt <- unlist(gregexpr (pattern,text)[[1]])

        #########################################
        # 03 check that each pattern within a word is valid and not used in an other char pattern
        #########################################
         for (charIndexStart in patFoundAt) 
               {#4loop03


           charIndexEnd = charIndexStart + nchar(pattern)-1

           if( sum(charSelectionTracker[charIndexStart:charIndexEnd]) == nchar(pattern) & sum(charSelectionTracker)> 0)
               {#PatExtract

             #track what letters have been used by character pattern
             charSelectionTracker[charIndexStart:charIndexEnd]=0

             #order/index in pattern 
             patIndex <- as.numeric(paste(as.numeric(charIndexStart),charIndexEnd,  sep = ''))

             innerPatternholder  <- data.frame(order= patIndex,charPattern = pattern)

             FoundcharPatternholder <- rbind(FoundcharPatternholder, innerPatternholder)
              }#PatExtract

            }#4loop03



     } #4loop02

  }#4loop01
```

Comment: I see you've used `gregexpr` in your code - would just setting some patterns like  `pat  <- c("th","er","f", "a", "e","t")` and then `regmatches(word,gregexpr(paste(pat,collapse="|"), word))` give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off losing the nested for-loops. `str_extract_all` and `str_count` from the stringr package may be useful to simplify the code:

```r
library(stringr)

## data
words <- c("father", "there", "after")
textPat <- paste(c("th", "er", "f","a","e","t"), collapse = "|")

## extract matching patterns 
charPat <- str_extract_all(words, textPat, simplify = TRUE) 
colnames(charPat) <- sprintf("charpat%02d", seq_len(ncol(charPat)))

## count matched patterns per word 
charPatLen <- str_count(words, textPat)

## combine into data.frame
cbind(data.frame(word = words, CharPatLen = charPatLen), charPat)
#>     word CharPatLen charpat01 charpat02 charpat03 charpat04
#> 1 father          4         f         a        th        er
#> 2  there          3        th        er         e          
#> 3  after          4         a         f         t        er
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I had a hard time install stringr as bitdefender kept block R and in the end I had to uses the admin account. I made the following change after some googling and testing to get your code to run with loaded files.


`wordLoaded <- read.csv("Wordlist.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # holding 1500 word
PatsLoaded <- read.csv("Character patterns list.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # holding 200 character patterns

words <- wordLoaded[,]
textPat <- paste(PatsLoaded[,], collapse = "|")`